# How to track code causing application to hang

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm maintaining an MFC application in some points it stop responding for 30 seconds , some times 1 minute or more. I'm supposed to fix that issue, I tried tracking the code[all methods in this class] and also the issue is still, I tried to pause debugging during this time and I got nothing as in this image

[image]

I want to know how to track the code that cause the application to stop responding

Comment: Can you attach with a debugger to the application, when it hangs? A stacktrace should show you then, where it is wasting time.

Comment: So GetMessage doesn't return and what we see is the current Codelocation, when you hit Break All?

Comment: Add trace logging (with timestamps), where you log when you enter and leave functions. Start with coarse logging, at a high level, then narrow it down until you find the exact function where this happens. Then narrow it further down by adding log statements inside the function.

Comment: Since you are using MFC, you can try to profile your code using VS proformance profiler. It will show you which function costs most of the time, (busy wait) or is blocking. (wait for a lock)

Comment: You can use WinDbg, attach when it hangs and then enter command `!locks` it will highlight locked critical sections and the owning threads, dump the call stacks of those threads and you should see threads waiting on each other's locks

Comment: GdiPlus running on a thread other than the GUI thread is somewhat alarming. Can you provide additional information on this, such as: Did you launch this thread? If so, why? What USER32 resources does it access? It's probably helpful to write a full dump to disk to capture the failure mode. This allows you to analyze it later, using WinDBG (as suggested by @EdChum). `!analyze -hang` may provide helpful information as well.

Comment: Have you tried using [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028)?

Comment: Sounds like you have inter-thread contention: one or more of your threads is dependant on one or more threads.  I would chart where you expect the code to go dependant on a set of scenarios to cover all the valid thread states and then check to make sure that the code flows as you would expect.  Particularly in relation to data being utilised by a thread which may be in use by another thread.

Answer (score 0):

1. add watch variable for any separate thread event

   - increment each watch variable inside its thread
   - also very useful can be flag if the thread/event is executing (especially for events)
   - you must set this flag on enter
   - end clear before exit
2. visualize watch variables somehow.

   - either use some debug print inside your App.
   - or use separate Window
   - or even better separate App connected with any IPC method. (this will work even if your App UI hangs)

When the app hangs just see which variables are incrementing and which not

with flags you can determine exact what is hanging up on you ...

Good luck with debuging.